# How to update apk in google play console after rejection application?

Tags: android, google-play, app-store, google-apps, google-play-console

I have uploaded an application in google play console. They rejected my application due to Violation of Impersonation policy. Then I changed my logo and uploaded it again. Then they publish it on play store. When I uploaded the application in play console I Upload both new apk and play console logo. When I am installing the application in the phone then I see they updated only play store logo, not my new apk. How do I solve the problem?

Comment: got any mail for app rejected/published from google? if not wait for confirmation

Answer (score 3):

Sometimes it takes more than 24 hrs to publish the app and become available for download from the google play store. Don't worry.

However, I would like to recommend you check if you have chosen the **Full Rollout** option while publishing your application. Sometimes, the app is updated and people forget to click on the **Full rollout** button.

Answer (score 1):

Was questioning the same thing yesterday. I violated the privacy policy and needed to add a policy into the url needed. And clicked "Resubmitted", at the side you will see "processing request" or something like that? Yes, you have to wait to let Google Play Store review your app to make sure you have fixed what they pointed out the first time.

So don't worry, give it some time.

Comment: Thaks for your reply. Shall I wait or send mail to google developer team because It already takes 19 hours.

Comment: sure, if it makes u feel less worried, go ahead!